# How to Create a File instance from the Jar/Classpath

Tags: java, file, maven, executable-jar

I have an executable JAR that has a file in it that i want to open as a java.io.File instance from code (not InputStream or anything else...just File).

Its a maven project and the file is at the root of "src/main/resources/file.xxx"
The file is located at the root directory of the jar after packaging(verified that its there).

My first attempt: FileNotFoundException

```
java.io.File myFile = new java.io.File("file.xxx");
someMethodThatUsesTheFile(myFile); //I really need it to be a file!!!
```

Other attempts: FileNotFoundException

```
java.io.File myFile = new java.io.File("/file.xxx");
java.io.File myFile = new java.io.File("classpath:file.xxx");
java.io.File myFile = new java.io.File("classpath:/file.xxx");
```

I am not sure whats really going on. Web Apps can easily just load everything from the webapp root directory, Im confused as to why JAR apps behave differently.

Additional Info:

- Using Java8 as runtime/build
- command to run the JAR: "java -jar myjar.jar"
- Application Code and file are both located in the same jar

Comment: You can not access a resource that is _inside_ a jar as a `File` instance. If you have control over `someMethodThatUsesTheFile` method, you should change it to accept an `InputStream` instead.

Comment: Resources in JARs are not files, and `File` objects cannot be constructed with URL arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: It is not a "File", so you just cant do it.

The JAR file is a File, but not its contents.

**Alternatives would be:**

- Try other overloaded versions of that method, InputStreams are
  usually your options, you can load it using this code:

  InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.xxx");
- Move that file out of the JAR and into the same directory of the JAR (consider the security risks)

Answer (score -2):

Try this one may help you :

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("src/main/resources/file.xxx");
File file= new File(url.toURI());
```

Comment: The `src` directory won't be there at runtime, and even it it was, that is not a correct path to the resource. Try it.